# ExecuteAsync Changes Passed Dynamic Parameters Names

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dapper

I am trying to insert form data to a table using a stored procedure by calling the ExecuteAsync method of Dapper. After sending the parameters names are changed.

```
public static async Task<bool> Insert(DynamicParameters dp)
{
    int IsSuccessed;
    using (SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection(con))
    {
        IsSuccessed = await c.ExecuteAsync("AddStudent", dp, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
    }
    return IsSuccessed > 0 ? true : false;
}
```

Parameters are changed showing in a sql  server Profiler

```
declare @p8 nvarchar(100)
set @p8=NULL
exec AddStudent @Name1=N'Ahmad',@TazkiraNumber1=N'890',@TazkiraPage1=N'0987',@TazkiraVolume1=N'8',@GenderID1=N'1',@VisitorSourceID1=N'2',@msg=@p8 output
select @p8
```

The following code make a dynamic parameters from form collection:

```
var dp = new DynamicParameters();
foreach (string key in form.Keys)
{
    dp.Add(key.ToString(), form[key]);
}
```

I am getting form data using IFormCollection and creating DynamicParameters from the key and value of form collection and pass the dynamic parameter to the ExecuteAsync method and it calls the stored procedure to insert the data to the tables. The process of executing the stored procedure fails.

I run the SQL server profiler and observed that 1 is appended to each parameter as @Name became @Name1.

Any idea why is this happing?

Comment: What is the value for `dp`? I made a test with `DynamicParameters dp = new DynamicParameters();
            dp.Add("name", "Tom");
            dp.Add("age", 5);`, it works correctly.

Comment: adding parameters manually works but not dynamically. I edited the question and included the dp code

Comment: what is the value for `form`? Share us the complete code which could reproduce your issue.

Comment: @TaoZhou I included the code in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this issue, it is caused by that, `StringValues` is failed to converted to the `DbType`.

Try code below:

```
    foreach (string key in form.Keys)
    {
        dp.Add(key.ToString(), form[key].ToString());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was a collection of `System.Guid` I was trying to pass.

```
var guids = new List<System.Guid>()
guids.Add(new System.Guid());//for the brevity of example
guids.Add(new System.Guid());//for the brevity of example
parameters.Add("@parameterName", guids);
```

I had to change the last line like below.

```
parameters.Add("@parameterName", string.Join(",", guids));
```